# Symfony2 profiler on Behat/Mink to test mails

Tags: php, symfony, behat, mink

I'm trying to use Behat to test my mails on my Symfony2 app, following this doc http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/using_the_profiler_with_minkbundle.html

I think the doc isn't up to date and I'm stuck.

I followed all the steps and get this scenario:

```
@mink:symfony2
Scenario: Registration Success
  ...
  And I should get an email on "me@myproject.com" with:
  """
  To finish validating your account - please visit
  """
```

But I get the following error:

```
You need to tag the scenario with "@mink:symfony". Using the profiler is not supported by Behat\Symfony2Extension\Driver\KernelDriver
```

If I use `@mink:symfony` instead of `@mink:symfony2` I get:

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]            
  Session "symfony" is not registered.
```

**behat.yml**

```
default:
   context:
     class:  MyProject\BehatBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
   extensions:
       Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
       mink_driver: true
       kernel:
          env: test
          debug: true
          bundle: MyProjectBehatBundle
       Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
          base_url: 'http://myproject.local/app_test.php/'
          goutte: ~
          default_session: symfony2
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

> But I get the following error:
>
> `You need to tag the scenario with "@mink:symfony". Using the profiler is not supported by Behat\Symfony2Extension\Driver\KernelDriver`

This error is due to your own method `getSymfonyProfile()` that you copied from the doc ( http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/using_the_profiler_with_minkbundle.html ) but you forgot the '2' in the exception's message.

So you have to write `@mink:symfony2` instead of `@mink:symfony`, like at the beginning (and to correct your exception message).

Then I think you should :

1. Make sure you have the `"behat/mink-browserkit-driver"` (**MinkBrowserKitDriver**) that allows you to access Symfony2 profiler with Behat.
2. Then, in your `behat.yml` configuration file, the `default_session` key must refer to an *existing session*, which means you have to declare Mink sessions like this :

   ```
   extensions:
       ...
       Behat\MinkExtension:
           base_url: 'http://localhost:8000/app_test.php/'
           sessions: # Sessions here
               symfony2:                     # <-- HERE: Define the "symfony2" session KEY so you can write "@mink:symfony2"
                   symfony2: ~               # Then call BrowserKitDriver here

           goutte: ~                         # Your GoutteDriver
           selenium2: ~                      # Your Selenium2Driver
           default_session: symfony2         # symfony2|goutte
           javascript_session: selenium2     # For @javascript tags
   ```
3. Finally, you can call `@mink:symfony2` with you Scenario, as said earlier.
   Now that should work.

And I am sorry because I know this is a very old subject, but maybe that will help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To test emails you can use [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/), this tool runs a SMTP server which catches any message sent to it to display in a web interface.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/alexandresalome/mailcatcher)

Answer (score 0):

A YAML file is space sensitive. You forgot to place spaces for the behat extension:

```
default:
  context:
    class:  MyProject\BehatBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
      mink_driver: true
      kernel:
        env: test
        debug: true
      bundle: MyProjectBehatBundle
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: 'http://myproject.local/app_test.php/'
      goutte: ~
      default_session: symfony2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your driver is an instance of `Behat\Symfony2Extension\Driver\KernelDriver` (as per the error) which is correct. If you've copied the code from the link you quoted then your driver is failing the check `instanceof KernelDriver` so the only explanation is that you're missing

```
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Driver\KernelDriver;
```

from your context file.

`@mink:symfony2` has been the correct tag [for a long time](https://github.com/Behat/Symfony2Extension/commit/ff6a1e590e421cabcb1f7afd99ad6b01c3b731b6) but I guess the snippet in the docs was out of date at the time you copied it. That's a red herring in any case.